# Cleaner way to create pen highlight effect in css?

Tags: css

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JurKS/) showing the effect I wish to create

2 mandatory requisites:

1. i need a small spacing (padding/margin) between each highlighted
   row
2. the green highlight should only cover the length of the text on each line

I tried a mixture of `<div><span>text</span></div>` combos and could only ever get to 1. or 2. but never both, except with a table.

whilst im happy this content being in a table as it is tabular, im not happy with the end result as im splitting a paragraph across table rows which isnt cricket.

how to get the effect with just divs and spans?

Comment: A span with line-height wouldn't do it? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yqaw4/

Comment: @j08691: You should probably submit that as an answer, that seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Jivlain - I would but I'd like to heard from the OP to make sure it's what he's looking for. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: yes seems to work - just whenever i did it like this, the span would fill its container's height (a td), so the bg would fill. i will post the not-working span version when i get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
display: block;
float: left;
clear: both;
```

Here's an example I made:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gxhsq/

Comment: if i add a `margin-top` i get my requisite 1. and it seems to work. thanks